# how to remove array index by value in php?

Tags: php

Remove those array indexes whose value is 1

```
array (1=>1,2=>2,3=>1,4=>1,5=>3,6=>1);
```

result array as

```
array(2=>2,5=>3);
```

is there is a direct function in php? like

```
unset(key($a,1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One liner, using `array_diff` as

`$your_array = array_diff ( $your_array, [1] );`

Answer (score 2):

look to use [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$myArray = array (1=>1,2=>2,3=>1,4=>1,5=>3,6=>1);

$myArray = array_filter(
    $myArray,
    function($value) {
        return $value !== 1;
    }
);
```

Comment: You answer gives error **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on line 7"**.

Comment: @FatalError - what version of PHP are you using? I'm guessing < 5.3.0 - [Demo](http://3v4l.org/MOvZD) perhaps time you should upgrade to a supported version of PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry there was version problem.

Comment: @FatalError Welcome in 2015, this year PHP 7 gets probably released, so get your PHP up and running with upgrading it :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through it, check and unset -

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if($v == 1) {
        unset($array[$k]);
    }
}
```

Or use `array_filter()`

```
$newArr = array_filter($array, function($v) {
    return ($v != 1);
});
```

Or you can use `array_flip()` for some trick -

```
$temp = array_flip($array);
unset($temp[1]);
$array = array_flip($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `array_flip` and can use the below code:

```
<?php
  $arr = array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>1,4=>1,5=>3,6=>1);
  $arr1 = array_flip($arr);
  unset($arr1[1]);
  $arr = array_flip($arr1);
  print_r($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using array_search() and unset, try the following:

```
while(($key = array_search(1, $array)) !== false) {
   unset($array[$key]);
}
```